# Image display in asp.net from sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a column named picture in my database and executed a query to insert and update a picture but when i try to display it in my asp.net site it does not show,only blank.In my database under the Picture column it says  so it exists there but doesnt show?

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.EmployeeCollection)
            {
            <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="@item.Photo">
            }
```

Comment: What do you store in the database? Is it the image or is it a url?

Comment: it's the image that came from the url in the query

Comment: That doesn't clear it up for me, what is an example value of item.Photo? A src attribute must be a url.

Comment: Photo is a byte []

Comment: That doesn't work because src is a url, not a byte array.

Comment: Read the whole thing again before commenting

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing in encoded format, the create imageHandler.ashx which return image in response and then display to image tag.

Your image tab should contains below

```
 "~/imageHandler.ashx?id=" + id.ToString();
```

Handler code

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image";

using (System.IO.MemoryStream str = new System.IO.MemoryStream(objData.ToArray(), true))
{
       str.Write(objData.ToArray(), 0, objData.ToArray().Length);
       Byte[] bytes = str.ToArray();
       context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
}
```

If you are storing url then directly bind image url attribute

Comment: Since OP is using MVC maybe it would be better to show a Controller instead of ashx.

Comment: Thank you fixed it,the problem wasnt with the byte array converter but some other html errors not related to the current post.